# How to check key value pair in json string for message field in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, elk, logstash-file

Here is sample of log json string, message field is again a json string.

```
{
"service_id" => "sec-sip",
"@version" => "1",
"logplane" => "containerlogs",
"componentName" => "container",
"message" => "{"version":"1.0","timestamp":"2021-08-06T13:48:56.640+0000","severity":"info","service_id":"MANAGER@m.syslog","message":"santu  testtttttttttttttttttttttt","extra_data":{"manager":{"log_plane":"alarmlogs","alarm_raise_time":"1628251669506","alarm_update_time":"1628257736581","source_type":"MANAGER","alarm_instance_id":"1","alarm_proposed_repair_action":"Informational alarm no action required.","alarm_handler_specific_problem":null,"specific_problem":"Business Logic Updated","event_type":"Processing",}}}",
"version" => "0.2.0",
"timestamp" => "2021-08-06T16:47:13.736Z"
}
```

I need to change logplane value on the basis of [extra_data][manager][logplane] == "alarmlogs"

Can you please help me, how we can extract this key from message field and apply the condition?

I want to achieve given below.

```
 if [extra_data][manager][logplane] == "alarmlogs" {
          mutate {
            replace => {"[logplane]" => "informational"}
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to convert `string` to a `json` object using `json filter`. In your case, do something similar

```
 filter {
   json {
     source => "message"
     target => "json_message"
   }

   if [json_message][extra_data][manager][logplane] == "alarmlogs" {
      mutate {
        replace => {"[logplane]" => "informational"}
     }
   }
 }
```

Not sure you want to convert back this new `json object`